# x64dbg проблема со строками в модуле кода

Tags: reverse-engineering

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Перешел на x64dbg относительно недавно, и столкнулся вот с какой проблемой.
В модуле "код" x64dbg отказывается парсить строки, а именно он принимает строки за код, в ollydbg с этим все было хорошо.

как быть?

Заранее спасибо!

401000 - секция кода в которой есть строки, что видно из дампа, но x64dbg интерпретирует их как код

Comment: `В модуле "код" x64dbg отказывается парсить строки` - добавьте скриншот хотя бы. Сейчас не понятно что вы имеете в виду.

Answer (score 1):

Если речь об окне дизассемблера во вкладке CPU, то строки обычно там и не смотрят. Но если очень надо - выделяете те инструкции, которые являются строками, правой кнопкой по ним, и там есть  нечто вроде "считать ASCII строкой".

Comment: он интерпретирует их как код, из-за этого затрудняется чтение команд,  помечать так все участки как ASCII строки не вариант, т.к. их огромное количество

Comment: Могу лишь предложить воспользоваться другим инструментом (IDA, Radare, куча их) или отправить багрепорт разработчикам: https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbg/issues/